# How to write regex email expression in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

How to write email regular expression in Jmeter?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just use "(.+?)", it will work . Below is the example

```
<input type="email" value="madhu@gmail.com">
```

to extract email value just use regular expression as value="(.+?)"

[image]

Comment: you realize that this will also happily match `<input type="email" value="iamnotavalidemail!!!">`?

Comment: Yes. I should work. If you want try it in Jmeter and let me know. I am sure your regular expression won't work in this case.

Comment: The fact that it "will work" and won't fail for `<input type="email" value="iamnotavalidemail!!!">` is **bad**. How you are not getting it?

Answer (score 2):

[JMeter site has explanation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#regex) on the syntax of regex, and JMeter has a RegEx tester. You can validate email in many ways. The most basic validation is this:

```
[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}
```

(it will check that `@` is present, the characters before and after `@` are limited to allowed characters, and domain extension is at least 2 characters long).

This expression catches most common emails, although it would fail for more advanced (but still valid) emails (e.g. emails with IPs, international domains, and so on)

Comment: Your regular expression [A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,} won't work for <input type="email" value="iamnotavalidemail!!!"> in Jmeter. But value="(.+?)"> should work

Comment: @MadhuCheepati: OP wants "email regular expression". I provided one. You provided something that has no relation to email whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I solved this problem by using the Regular expression extractor and beanshell post processor.

**BeanShell sampler Code:-**

```
emailAd = vars.get("email");

emailAddr = vars.get("EmailAddress");

//log.info(email);  // if you want to log something to jmeter.log file

if(!emailAd.equals("0")) {

// Pass true if you want to append to existing file
// If you want to overwrite, then don't pass the second argument

f = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Errors.tsv", true);
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 


print(emailAddr +"\t"+ emailAd );


f.close();}
```